# Extraer valores de un string con split

Tags: javascript

Tengo un string el cual su valor es: `FL:18,PC:0,PD:L` y me gustaría extraer con `split` o algún método similar los valores `18,0,L`

```
cad.split(",")...
```

Comment: Hola Luis, te recomiendo que mires [ask] y que edites tu pregunta y nos muestres un poco de lo que llevas hasta el momento y cuales han sido tus problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el formato siempre seria el mismo podrias hacer:

```js
    let cadena="FL:18,PC:0,PD:L"
    let respuesta=cadena.split(',').map(el=>el.split(':')[1]).join(',');
    console.log(respuesta);
```

El primer `split(',')` separa la cadena en un array: ["FL:18","PC:0","PD:L"].

`map` nos sirve para recorrer el array y retornar un array, además en su interior  realizamos `el.split(':')` que nos serviría para separar por `:`; Todo esto nos retonaria: ["18","0","L"].

Como nuestro resultado es un array, nos tocaría unirlos con un `join(',')` para obtener le resultado requerido.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Shassain.